# Is there any way to prevent a background process from writing to the stdout channel when the shell is reading a command?

Tags: c, shell, unix

I'm writing a shell in C. The shell has internal and external commands. The external commands can be extended with an ampersand (&) so they run in the background.

When I type e.g `program&`, the `program` executes with no problem in the background, making the shell available while the program is executing.

But, the output of the `program` can get mixed with the normal output of the shell. And that's what I'm trying to fix, with no success.

Note: In the example above I talked about `program` as any other command. The `program` basically sleeps and then prints "Hello, World!". Also, "program" is in /bin/, which is my default directory of external commands.

```
sish> pwd
[current directory]
sish> program&
sish> [now if I don't type anything...] Hello, World!
[now the current command is being written here].
```

For example, in bash, this behavior is different, it seems that, if the user is "still" writing the command, the output of the background program is holding (or waiting), so the user can execute a program. Hence, not messing with the output.

I read a bit about signals, I tried to setup a signal handler that printed something on SIGCHLD but it also had the same behavior.

CODE:

```c
while(1) {
        int internal=0;
        int background=0;
        int redirect=0; // 1 - output ; 2 - input
                // those variables are not important for the question

        printf("sish> ");
        fgets(command,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin);
}
```

... (some lines that are not important for the question)

```c
            child = fork(); // pid_t child -> global variable
            if(!child) {

                if(redirect==1) { 

                    int fd = open(words[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,0660);
                    dup2(fd,1);
                    execlp(words[0],words[0],NULL);
                }

                else if(redirect==2) {

                    int fd = open(words[2],O_RDWR);
                    dup2(fd,0);
                    execlp(words[0],words[0],NULL);
                }

                else {

                    if(execvp(bin_path,words)==-1) {
                        printf("Error! Does the program exist?\n");
                    }
                }
            }
```

NOTES: 
- I KNOW I'M NOT CHECKING FOR ERRORS IN THE FORK, I WILL ADD THAT WHEN I SOLVE THIS BUG.
- I ALSO PRINTED THE STDERR WITH `perror`, I GOT NOTHING.

I expect this (e.g):

```
sish> pwd
[current directory]
sish> program&
sish> [I wait...] pwd
[current directory]
Hello, World!
```

Comment: As you are making the shell, you may spawn a thread that monitors stdin/stdout/stderr to see if data is available for reading by select(2)/kqueue(2) or something similar and queues them up in the order they arrived(or in the order the processes were spawned) meanwhile writing their output into someother temporary file. Although this doesn't seem to be very efficient and neither am I sure about this, just a random idea.

Comment: I haven't read your whole Q, but you should look into `stty tostop`: it will cause a background job to be stopped with `SIGTTOU` when trying to write to the controlling terminal: `stty tostop; (sleep 1; echo yup) &` => `yup` won't mess your terminal. Though you could easily set that flag with `tcsetattr()`, I don't think that a shell is supposed to mess with it -- it should be left as a preference to the user.